# Animate Element from Start Position to the Position of Another Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically I have two jQuery wrapped elements `$source` and `$target` where `$source` is a shim/placeholder.

I want to animate `$source` to the Position of `$target`. After the animation I am doing an `$target.replaceWith($source);`

I need to be able to do this no matter where `$source` and `$target` are in the DOM. Is there a jQuery plugin/easy way to accomplish this?

As for the problem I am trying to solve, I have two lists, and I'm trying to animate the last item from one list into the beginning of another one.

Here's my stab at it:

```
var moveItem = function ($sourceItem, $targetItem, callback, before) {
        var targetCord = $targetItem.css('position', 'absolute').offset();
        $targetItem.css('position', 'static');
        var sourceCord = $sourceItem.position();
        $targetItem[before? 'before': 'after']('<li class="shim"></li>');
        //diag('Shim Created.');
        var $newlyAddedShim = $targetItem[before ? 'prev' : 'next']();

        $sourceItem.css('position', 'absolute')
            .css({ left: sourceCord.left, top: sourceCord.top })
            .animate({ left: targetCord.left, top: targetCord.top }, 'slow', function () {
                $newlyAddedShim.replaceWith($sourceItem.css('position', 'static'));
                callback();
            });
    };
```

If a generic solution is not possible, this is the markup structure I am constrained to where `$source` and `$target` are `li` in different `ul`:

```
div.row > div.col > ul > li
          div.col > ul > li
```

(Each adjacent involved list is in it's own div.col; position is inherited as static)

I'd like to be able to do:
`$source.animateTo($target)`

Comment: This is really dependent on HTML/CSS markup as the position property is extremely relevant to this question. Although I suppose there are hacky ways around that but they would require a lot of ugly DOM manipulation.

Comment: @Ennui Edited question to include my markup structure/constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's $.offset function
http://api.jquery.com/offset/

```
var offset = $('#containerToMoveTo').offset();

$('#elementToAnimate').animate({
   top: offset.top,
   left: offset.left
});
```

Should do it, if not, try giving the #elementToAnimate position absolute right before animating.

```
$('#elementToAnimate').css('position', 'absolute');
```